# How can i add a description in a ScrollView on separate lines?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

How can i create a description within a scrollview?
i would like to place a date on none line and a title on a separate line, but even with spaces and pressing enter it creates all on one line.

The code works well i just need help on being able to control what i write on what line. For example

date
location
title
expiry

instead of writing them on separate lines it all goes onto the same line. Even using enter, tab, spaces.

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
 TextView mTitleWindow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleWindow);
 TextView mMessageWindow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageWindow);

    mTitleWindow.setText("BATMAN IS PART OF THE DC TRINITY");
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String someMessage = "hello     hi" ;
    stringBuilder.append(someMessage);

    mMessageWindow.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
```

**layout**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleWindow"
            android:layout_width="352dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageWindow"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="455dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/titleWindow" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Is there problem only with `titleWindow` text? Or both textviews doesn't split text to lines?

Comment: Both of them won’t split

Comment: Try to set `wrap_content` height for all views except `ScrollView`.

Comment: It still won’t split. I think if anything I’d have to change someMessage in the mainactivity but not sure exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @D_TECK use "\n" in string variable value for the separate line in message.

```
String someMessage = "hello     \n hi";
```

Comment: If it works fine than accept the answer so it will be helpful to others also.

Comment: can i ask another question?